# Background process in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process

I am writing a Web app that will need to run a background process that will poll a web service every minute or so and then query my Rails db and send out alerts to users of the app via Twitter. I have researched this a lot but I feel I am just going around in circles. I have come across delayed_job, background_job and a few other options like creating a custom daemon suggested in a Railscast. Does anyone have any suggestions for the best way to do this? The process will have to run constantly in the background and won't be triggered by an event in the front end. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just create a rake task and add it to your CRON execution?

You can even use [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to configure this for you.

Comment: Will this work on localhost? I update my crontask but I don't think the rake is getting run. I can run my rake manually in the terminal. I could potentially naming my rake wrong in the whenever schedule.rb file.

Comment: What do you mean with "will this work on localhost?"? Are you asking if it will work on you development machine?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I've updated the crontab to include my rake but when in run rails s the experiment I am trying is not working. Is this because it is being run on my development machine?

Comment: Looking more into this I can see that I have to say whether it should run on development or production.

Comment: **rails s** is not related to this, once your crontab is updated it is going to run. Also, make sure you are changing the right crontab file, if you change your LOCAL development machine, it will only affect your local development machine. You should also try to use whenever instead of changing the crontab yourself.

Comment: Yes I think I have only set the crontab for production. Hopefully I'll figure this out soon and accept your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I used Beanstalkd for this and can recommend it.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/243-beanstalkd-and-stalker

Comment: I think this might work with God. Thanks for the reply I'll let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use cron for tasks that has to be executed every X minutes, hours etc.

gem whenever is usefull to setup this with rails: https://github.com/javan/whenever

I don't know much about delayed_job. But you can check out some tutorials, for example this article on heroku: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job

Comment: Github left delayed_job a long time ago and built resque to fix it's issues -> https://github.com/defunkt/resque

Comment: Yes you're right. I updated my anwser ;-) and I't seems I suggested the same solution like you.

Answer (score 0):

I used delayed_job for our application.

While working on this, we researched many sites and finally we are able to apply it.

We apply our experiences in the following link

http://www.kyybaventures.com/blog/rails-delayed-job#more-2916

Hope this will help to get started with background process in rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

We can either use `backgroundrb` or `unix crontab`.

`Crontab` will do the job if you don't want to send any `heavy loaded process to run asynchronously` during the request process cycle of the application.

`Backgroundrb` consumes lot of memory and cpu in production environment if any of the process hangs out. Also we need to configure a `monitor tool` to make sure that the background process is running.